# Is it possible to apply a decorator to a line in python?

Tags: python, logging, decorator

As you may now, the common usage of decorator is for example:

```
@log
def func(...)
```

What actualy takes func as parameter returns a function what takes func as an argument, like :

```
def log(func):
    def function_wrapper(*args , **kwargs):
    log_enter_func(func, args, kwargs)

    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    log_exit_func(func, result )
    return result
```

In code above, logging of function calls and returns are fine, without hand- made log (...) entries with just @log decorator over a function. 
So its easy to remove after testing, so logging does not consume time.

But is it possible to hang it just to lines of code? 
Like for loops, etc, so something like :

```
def func(...):
 ...
@log
    for x in range(whatever)
```

Taking the line as soft of a function, accessing in some kinf of args to x, whatever ( variables and code in the line) cause actualy everything is a function in python?

Or maybe there is some kind of method to apply decorator to a method and propagate it to source lines in a function ?

The idea is to make a brief logging of whats happens in every line without lots of hand- written log entries like
log.info(msg)
in many lines of code

Any ideas about that?
I v tryed to inspect the func. __ code __  built- in, but its python byte- code there , not source code...

Comment: Looking at how decorators work, which is basically `function = decorator(function)`. What in your idea would be the `function` argument and where should the result be stored?

Comment: you could move the code you want to log into a function and decorate that function.

Comment: Klaus D. i dont know , i m asking, is it possible to trait the line of code like function and decorate it? With inspect(f.__code__) i can propagate it to BYTE code, but logging the byte code is kinda weird... MooingRawr i am doing exactly that it the example. I want to auto- log LINES OF CODE.

Comment: You can use a context manager to wrap lines of code like how a decorator wraps a function.

Comment: what is this  context manager?

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what context managers are for. These are triggered with a `with` block, and define code that runs on entering and exiting the block.

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers).

Comment: can you please write short example how to use it, mby it will not work for my task...

Answer (score 1):

No, decorators are meant to wrap functions only.

That said, you can run your line inside a function and then use the decorator.

```
def func(...):
    ...

    @log
    def _f(): #you can define this inside func() if you want
        for x in range(whatever):
            ...

    #call decorated function
    _f()
```

Comment: yes but lol,you wouldnt do that   for every line of code, basic idea is remove unessesary writing..

Comment: You can add as many lines you want in the function. In this case is a for-loop as in your example, but it can be an entire script as well. You should post a more specific example. From your code, it's hard to say what is your goal. If you are trying to log events, have a look at the logging module in standard library! https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Answer (score 1):

While it may not be possible to address each line of a function with a decorator, I think you may be able to log each line using the following method:

[Python Decorator for printing every line executed by a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163436/python-decorator-for-printing-every-line-executed-by-a-function)

The idea is to create a debug context, then the debug decorator wrapper around the debug_context function. This creates a log of local variables to std.out