# Python Decorator for printing expression result executed by a function

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print out result of every expression in a python function. Is there a decorator that can do the job here?  What i want is:

```
@print_decorator
def Explanation():
    5 == 5.0 == 5 + 0j
    5 is not 5.0 is not 5 + 0j
    some_dict = {}
    some_dict[5.0] = "Ruby"
    5.0 in some_dict
    (5 in some_dict) and (5 + 0j in some_dict)
```

Then I get output whenever I call Explanation:

```
True
True
True
True
```

Just like the following ExplanationWithPrint print(the code seems ugly):

```
def ExplanationWithPrint():
    print(5 == 5.0 == 5 + 0j)
    print(5 is not 5.0 is not 5 + 0j)
    some_dict = {}
    some_dict[5.0] = "Ruby"
    print(5.0 in some_dict)
    print((5 in some_dict) and (5 + 0j in some_dict))
```

May be similar with [Python Decorator for printing every line executed by a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163436/python-decorator-for-printing-every-line-executed-by-a-function).